# FileSystemWatcher renamed event not raised when I rename the folder it's watching out

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I've configured a `FileSystemWatcher` in order to it watches out on a folder `C:\folder`.

It's suddenly come up me a problem when I've changed the name of the folder it's watching out to another one, and it doesn't raise anything.

The question is: Does a `FileSystemWatcher` raise some event when changes are made on the same "object" it's watching out?

Comment: The question is: "What have you tried so far?"

Comment: If you want to detect the folder getting renamed then you need another FSW that looks at the parent folder.  That does stop getting practical in a hurry.

Comment: @HansPassant, or use IncludeSubdirectories but then cope with lots of events that may come faster then you can process them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renaming the directory you are watching will not raise a notification. Notifications are only raised for entries inside the directory you are watching. That is expected behavior which is explicit documented in remarks block for [FileSystemWatcher.Renamed Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed).

Comment: The link-only answer demon has raised its ugly head.  It attempted to redirect but died.  I suspect you want some part of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher